# Возможно ли сократить данный код, используя тернарный оператор?

Tags: javascript

Имеется две строчки, где **value** и **n** - любые два числа (**value** > **n**):

```js
let answer = value / n;
return (answer % 1 == 0) ? answer : -1;
```

Возможно ли здесь обойтись без переменной answer, чтобы записать всё выражение в одну строчку? Только без этого:

```js
return (value / n % 1 == 0) ? value / n : -1; 
// не нужно, чтобы value / n выполнялось два раза
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, вообще без тернарного оператора && возвращает последний оператор, в случае когда истина, либо возвращает ложь. А || возвращает первое которое истина, запятая возвращает последний результат.

```js
function div(value, n){return n=value/n, n%2==0&&n||-1;}

console.log(div(8, 2));
console.log(div(8, 3));
```